# Action bar rendering issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am new to Android Studio. I had this action bar disappearing in design panel. Basically nothing was being rendered on the design view. no action bar no textView nothing. then i read that i should switch my theme to some other theme and that worked but i wanted to keep the normal apptheme. API changing didnt do anything to it.
what worked was:
changing the appcompat line in build.gradle to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
```

it started working like a charm until today.I was learning how fragments work so i made two blank fragments and the rendering issue came again. just to check it wasnt some bad luck:
I made a new project.
problem was there.
changed build.gradle file.
problem disappeared.
added 2 blank frags (with xml) to the proj.
problem came again.

now ill tell you what all ive done which doesnt work for me:

- updated android studio
- build.gradle appcompat code change
- theme change (works but i want apptheme)
- API change
- changing style.xml(brings back textView in the design view but not the action bar)

[image: android studio screenshot image link]

please help.following is the stack :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:209)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:89)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:68)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:277)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:161)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:288)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have you solved it already?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use more stable version of the support library see if the issue goes away?

revisions for version 26 as stated [Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#26-1-0) are: 26.1.0, 26.0.2, 26.0.1

Comment: `dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}`